# FlotCharts: Bars with striped lines

Tags: flot

Showing bars striped lines rather than solid color is possible ?

For example:
[image]

Comment: Flot does not support this, it only supports solid colors and vertical [gradients](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#specifying-gradients).

Answer (score 2):

I think `flot` really missed a chance here to allow the user to specify a function to generate the fill instead of just colors or gradients.  I've made a simple modification to the code [here](https://github.com/larsenmtl/flot) and created a pull request (the `flot` github looks abandoned, though, so I'm not sure their is anyone to accept the request).

With this change, you can "strip" the bars like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script data-require="flot@0.8.2" data-semver="0.8.2" src="https://rawgit.com/larsenmtl/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="pattern" width="20" height="20" style="display:none"></canvas>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      
      var p_can = $('#pattern').get(0),
        p_ctx = p_can.getContext('2d');
      p_ctx.beginPath();
      p_ctx.moveTo(0,0);
      p_ctx.lineTo(20,20);
      p_ctx.stroke();

      var d1 = [
        [0, 1],
        [2, 8],
        [4, 5]
      ];

      $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{
        data: d1,
        bars: {
          show: true,
          fill: function(a,b) {
            var ctx = $('#placeholder>canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
            return ctx.createPattern(p_can, 'repeat');
          }
        }
      }], { });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I'm creating an additional canvas element, drawing a 45 degree line and then using that to create a fill pattern for the bars.